# Жизненный цикл android приложения

Tags: java, android, service

Для реализации задачи, мне необходим `Service` который запускается при старте приложения и останавливается при закрытии.

Я делал следующим образом: 
`MainActivity` - основное активити (Если оно закрывается, то можно сказать, что пользователь закончил использовать приложение). Поэтому в `onDestroy` я прописываю `stopService`. 
Но тут появилась проблема при повороте экрана так же отрабатывается метод `onDestoy`, следовательно сервис убивается.

Как отловить Глобальный `onDestroy` когда приложение убивается, чтобы убить `Service`.

Comment: А это проблема, что сервис перезапустится? Он же в onCreate() после поворота снова запустится, как я понимаю.

Comment: Какой смысл в сервисе, который живёт вместе с активити? Сервисы обычно используются тогда, когда они должны работать даже когда все активити закрыты.

Comment: @eugeneek, может так надо :) Но вы правы, похоже на промах в архитектуре приложения.

Comment: не забывайте, что кроме контекста активити, у вас еще есть контекст апликейшна, у которого тоже есть жизненный цикл, и вот он как раз - цикл всего приложения

Comment: @SviatVolkov вот в том и вопрос что цикл Application начинается в application onCreate,а заканчивается он чем ?

Answer (score 1):

Если привязываете сервис к жизненному циклу активити, то от таких "приколов" не уйти.

Если перезапуск сервиса критичен, то запускайте его в `Application.onCreate()`, по умолчанию сервис работает в процессе приложения и по сути его не надо в этом случае останавливать самому. Система его прикончит вместе с объектом Application, когда сама решит.

Конечно оба варианта имеют свои плюсы и минусы, какой лучше, может вообще ни один из них, выбирать вам исходя из сути и назначения сервиса.

Comment: Я делаю приложение для радио: 
В сервисе есть две функции: 
1) Запуск плеера для проигрывания
2) Получение информации о текущем треке (Посылает запрос на сервер, когда трек закончился) 

Если сервис будет жить в фоне, то он все время работы будет посылать запросы на сервер.

Comment: Можно же кроме состояний Запущен\Не Запущен придумать еще состояние Пауза.

Answer (score 1):

При повороте до `onDestroy()` вызывается ещё один метод жизненного цикла `onSaveInstanceState()`. При обычном уничтожении активити (когда пользователь закончил пользоваться приложением) этот метод не вызывается. Можете в нём ставить флаг и проверять его в `onDestroy`. Если флаг установлен, то не стопить сервис.